# Why is the $ \mathbb{Z} $ - Hodge conjecture false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, hodge-theory

I wish someone well initiated in the area , told me , why the $ \mathbb{Z} $ - Hodge conjecture is wrong, which allowed to change its state by tensoring by $ \mathbb{ Q } $ to become as it is known today, as : rational Hodge conjecture.
I recently learned that there are two reasons for that, which allowed such a change. First, because of the presence of torsion elements , and the second reason is that a mathematician in the $ 90 $s , managed to produce a counter-example based on $ K_3 $ - surfaces. I do not know what that means.

Is someone can explain to me all this?

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atiyah and Hirzebruch observed in *Analytic cycles on complex manifolds*, Topology, 1 (1962), that the group $H^{2p}(X,\mathbf{Z})$ may contain torsion elements and that a torsion element vanishes in the $H^{2p}(X,\mathbf{C})$, and therefore satisfies obviously the Hodge condition. Then you could ask whether the integral Hodge conjecture is true modulo torsion, in particular as soon as the $H^{2p}(X,\mathbf{Z})$ is torsion free. But Kollár showed in *Trento examples. Classification of irregular varieties* (Trento, 1990), 134–135.
Lecture Notes in Math. 1515, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1992, that this is not the case for a general hypersurface in $\mathbf{P}^4$ of large enough degree. There is a very nice *exposé* of Arnaud Beauville on the Hodge conjecture at the séminaire Bourbaki, which deals also with the integral Hodge conjecture and gives examples about it, that you can find online here :

http://math.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/Hodge.pdf